# Error occurred prerendering page "/404". TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

I have a web app built using Next.js version 13.4.13, that's hosted on AWS amplify.

My first deployment had no issues and my web app functioned correctly. But when I tried to make changes and re-deploy the app, I got the below error,

```
[WARNING]: Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

I am using the latest `app` router and I do not have a custom error page.

But I when I delete my AWS amplify app, and then create a new app and then perform a new deployment, then it works fine.

I'm not using `useContext` in my code. I'm using only `useState` (which has no error reported).

My `app` file directory is as follows,

- app

  - globall.css
  - layout.tsx
  - page.tsx

And my `page.tsx` contents is as follows,

```
import Company from "@/sections/Company";
import {
  Mission,
  Services,
  Team,
  Hero,
  Navbar,
  Details,
  Footer,
} from "../sections";

const Page = () => (
  <div className="bg-primary-black overflow-hidden">
    <Navbar />
    <Hero />
    <div className="relative">
      <Mission />
      <div className="gradient-03"></div>
      <Details />
      <div className="gradient-04"></div>
      <Services />
      <div className="gradient-06"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="gradient-left"></div>
      <Team />
      <div className="gradient-right"></div>
      <Company />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export default Page;
```

Anyone has any idea what's the issue?

Added:

I am adding the layout.tsx bellow.

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Linknit",
  description: "Linknit: Link your every need for a study abroad",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <link rel="icon" href="linknit-logo.svg" />
      <body>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Running `pnpm build` on local does not show any errors regarding the prerendering /500 or /404.

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /                                      56.3 kB         135 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              78.3 kB
  ├ chunks/291-c577ad0e930e9c15.js         25.9 kB
  ├ chunks/2bece34a-8484c688a7ebdb4e.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-60fd3ca2e8e14587.js    211 B
  └ chunks/webpack-d7bc6ccbc9bf2471.js     1.67 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   182 B          75.7 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              75.5 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-510ec8ffd65e1d01.js   45 kB
  ├ chunks/main-ded02ef5ae1b734f.js        28.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-e3a45f45b4fcedf8.js  196 B
  └ chunks/webpack-d7bc6ccbc9bf2471.js     1.67 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're simply trying to read a property from context that is not initialised, specifically on your 500 page, so there's also something going wrong on the actual page you're trying to render.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. But like mentioned above, I do not have a custom error page for 404 or 500. Will creating those pages help?

Comment: @JasonPark could you share the Layout file please? And perhaps it's also necessary to share the files of everything that's nested in Layout.

Comment: Hello Webber. I just shared the layout file in the body of my question. I did also add some more detail of the situation. You mentioned "everything" that's nested in Layout. Correct me if I am wrong, but does this mean to share every component? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Nothing too obvious pops out, but probably it's a good idea to remove everything from _app and then granularly add things until it breaks. Trial and error. I suspect it's the Inter instantiation that fails or something similar. Since `_app` is also used for error pages that is likely to be the problem.